# ZK Device Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Мне нужно разработать веб сервис который сможет получать информацию с ZK Finger Device. В сети есть существующие библиотеки написаны на Python 2 (https://pypi.org/project/zklib/)  нужно аналогичное реализовать на ASP.Net. Может кто-нибудь посоветовать с чего начать, структуру проекта, заранее благодарен?

Comment: С чего начать что? Как писать веб сервисы? Как получать данные с девайса? Как писать проект на asp.net? каком asp.net? MVC? WebForms? Core?

Comment: Как написать веб сервис, правильная структура, нужно на ASP Web API.

Comment: [Раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), [Два](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)